# URL page not found error

Tags: magento, url, redirect

I have a webshop with magento wherein :

- abc.com/staff is giving page not found error
- abc.com/staff/ is loading the page correctly.

There is a difference of "/" in both the URLS. I have other CMS pages in magento such as contact-us which are working perfectly fine. Need assistance in this scenario about what is going wrong.

Comment: try rename `url_key` maybe you have module `staff`?

Answer (score 0):

You have entered page url while creating that cms page as `staff/` so replace this page url to `staff`.

Comment: Nope . My page url is staff and not staff/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a specific rule for url `staff` anywhere (ie: in `.htaccess` file) or a directory `staff` in Magento root folder or an older rewrite rule in database.